# Regex to replace every end of sentence with a carriage return

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to regex to replace every `'. '` with `'.' + Chr(13)`.  Here's what I've tried:

```
x = x.replace(/. /g,/.\n/);
```

Comment: So... what is your problem? Btw, `\n` is a line feed, not a carriage return.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.` is a wildcard in regex.  You need to escape it.  Also, replace with a string literal.  Also, I didn't even catch this but Felix Kling points out, `\n` is not a carriage return.

```
x = x.replace(/\. /g, "\r");
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to escape the `.` and replace with a string, not a regular expression:

```
x = x.replace(/\. /g, '.\n');
```

Also, if you really meant `Chr(13)`, that's `\r`, not `\n`.

Answer (score 2):

Merely replace your expression with `/\. /`